# Action Delegate With Generic Parameter

Tags: .net, linq, delegates

Have some code:

```
using (var ctx = new testDataContext())
        {
            var options = new DataLoadOptions();
            options.LoadWith<TableA>(p => p.TableB);
            ...
            var tmp = ctx.TableA.Where(p => p.TableB != null);
            ...
        }
```

Want to wrap it like:

```
Action<T> test = x => {
    using (var ctx = new testDataContext())
        {
            var options = new DataLoadOptions();
            options.LoadWith<TableA>(p => typeof(x));
            ...
            var tmp = ctx.TableA.Where(p => p.GetType().GetProperty(x) != null);
            ...
        }
}
test(TableB);
test(TableC);
```

Or something like that.

The idea is - to use same method, for diffrent tables, which are passed as parameter, to some function.

I know about linq2sql inheritance, but i want to know, is it possible to do another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the particular property/properties you're going to inspect are fixed in number and known at compile time, then adding a particular interface for those tables (via partial class, I'd assume) would likely be easiest and still type-safe.  Otherwise, you're looking at reflection, or using dynamic, or perhaps using Dynamic LINQ depending on the goals.

Giving a more concrete example might help since it's not clear to me whether it's something you want to take specific tables that fit a pattern for, or any table no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

If you can introduce a common interface for the tables - you can write a function\delegate that has a parameter of that interface's type and pass each table as that parameter.